# How to lower loss in Symbolic Regression Julia

Tags: julia

When running Symbolic Regression on a certain modelling problem, the loss of the estimated equation seems to be very arbitrary. Sometimes /rarely the loss is arround 1e7 and some other times gets stuck ata around 1e17 or 1e13.

I read the manual of the SymbolicRegression.jl package but couldnt find a way to somehow influence the algorithm in a way so the loss is consistent. The code is as following:

```
using SymbolicRegression,SymbolicUtils
X = ones(3,6)
X[1,1:3] .= 40
X[2,1:3] .= 55000
X[3,1] = 2.0
X[3,2] = 4.0
X[3,3] = 6.0
X[1,4:6] .= 40
X[2,4:6] .= 45000
X[3,4] = 2.0
X[3,5] = 4.0
X[3,6] = 6.0

X;
y = [3.42e10,1.22e10,8.99e9,5.79e12,1.4e12,1.3e12]



options = Options(binary_operators=(+, *, /, -),npopulations=20,maxsize=60);


hall_of_fame = EquationSearch(X, y; niterations=10000, options=options, numprocs=15,parallelism=:multiprocessing);

dominating = calculate_pareto_frontier(X, y, hall_of_fame, options);

eqn = node_to_symbolic(dominating[end].tree, options)
```

Comment: What does `loss is consistent` mean?